# Why does $f(1) = f(0) + 1$?

Tags: functions

I do not understand this answer. While I understand the outputs for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, why at the end does $f(1) = f(0) + 1$?  Where does the $f(1)$ come from? Previously he stated $f(0+1) = f(0) + 1$ which is part of the $f(x + 1)$ function, but why does he make the jump next to $f(1)$? See question below:

We have:
$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \tag{i}$

$f(x  +1) = f(x) + x + 1 \tag{ii}$

Substituting $x = 0$ in (i):

$f(0) = c \tag{iii}$

Substituting $x = 1$ in (i)

$f(1) = a + b + c \tag{iv}$

Substituting $x = 0$ in (ii)

$$f(0 + 1) = f(0) + 1$$

Therefore, $f(1) = f(0) + 1$.

Therefore $a + b + c = c + 1$, using (iii) and (iv).

Therefore $a + b = 1$.

Comment: All looks fine to me, which part do you not understand, the part $f(0+1)=f(1)=f(0)+1$ seems logical, no?

Comment: Did you mean $f(x) = ax^2 + b\color{red}{x} + c$?  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: No need for this N. F. Taussig.  Clearly this is a typo, everyone else has been very helpful, so probably best you take your lectures somewhere else

Comment: @egreg fixed!  feel better?

Comment: @egreg there is no sarcasm there.. there is no tone on the internet, so rather difficult to make that assumption.  I hadn't actually realised you could edit a question once it had been posed.  But thank you for pointing it out.  Have a wonderful rest of your day

Answer (score 2):

The train of reasoning is as follows:

- Attempt to discover $f(0)$ in two different ways: using the first equation, and using the second equation. The first equation gives us that it is $c$; the second equation expresses it in terms of $f(1)$, so we need to find that next.
- Attempt to determine $f(1)$ using the first equation. The result is $a+b+c$.
- Substitute the now-known value of $f(1)$ (i.e. $a+b+c$) into the expression from the first step.

---

If you're trying to determine information about an object, a common technique is to try and discover some property of that object from two different angles. For example,

- the answer you quoted finds $f(0)$ from two different angles (using, respectively, the two given equations);
- a combinatorial proof of $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} = 2^n$ finds "the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$" in two different ways (namely "the number of subsets of size $i$, summed over each $i$" and "the number of ways to specify a subset uniquely").

Comment: Thank you Patrick.  Apologies the first equation is indeed ax^2 + bx +c, which I think you gathered.

So here is my confusion.  You say that the second equation expresses it in terms of f(1)?  The second equation is f(x+1) which f(0) is = f(0+1).  Are you saying that f(0+1) is the same as f(1)?  I had assumed they were different?  Yes of course 0+1 is 1, but are they equivalent?   It seems I am lacking a basic understanding of something here.  Apologies it has been some 20 years since I last studied functons

Comment: @A.Lucas Yes, if $x=y$ then $f(x)=f(y).$ "Equals may be substituted for equals." Since $0+1=1,$ it follows that $f(0+1)=f(1).$

Comment: Understood, for some reason I had thought they would be different.. thank you again